# asp.net timespan

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I'm using a timespan function to work out the number of days, this value is then added to a text box and saved to the database.

I have recently added a radio button as a half day so it if is checked it adds 0.5 days holiday rather than 1 day. This seems to work correctly when displayed in the text box before being saved. However, when it actually saves and updates the database shows a value of 1 rather than 0.5 as shown in text box.

The fieldtype in the database for this field was originally set to 'int'but when I added the half day it would not save as it was trying to save a decimal figure, I have since changed this fieldtype to 'decimal' as it thought this would be more suitable.. i'm not sure if this is correct or it should be something different?

I cannot seem to figure out why it is not saving the value specified in the text box...any suggestions

```
 Private Sub btnHNoDays_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnHNoDays.Click

    'declare dates
    Dim dtStart As Date = txtHStart_Date.Text
    Dim dtEnd As Date = txtHEnd_Date.Text

    'timespan function used to minus one date to another and produce a value 
    Dim ts As TimeSpan = (dtEnd - dtStart)

    If RadioButton1.Checked Then

        ts = (dtEnd - dtStart) - TimeSpan.FromDays(0.5)
    Else
        ts = (dtEnd - dtStart)
    End If

    ' the value is set to to textbox.
    txtNoofDays.Text = ts.TotalDays()

    ' the today days value
    Console.WriteLine(ts.TotalDays)
End Sub



Protected Sub btnHRequestSave_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles btnHRequestSave.Click
    'collect data
    Dim Sdate = txtHStart_Date.Text
    Dim Edate = txtHEnd_Date.Text
    Dim NoofDays = txtNoofDays.Text
    Dim notes = TxtHRequestNotes.Text
    Dim username = lblHolidayRequestLIU.Text

    'define connection

    Dim HRequestConnection As New SqlConnection
    HRequestConnection.ConnectionString = HolidayRequestSqlDataSource.ConnectionString

    'create command
   Dim HRequestInsert As New SqlCommand("Insert into HolidayRequests (username, RequestDateStart, RequestDateEnd, RequestTotalDays, RequestNotes) VALUES (@username, @Sdate, @Edate, @NoofDays, @notes)", HRequestConnection)

    'define parameters
    HRequestInsert.Parameters.Add("username", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 20).Value = lblHolidayRequestLIU.Text
    HRequestInsert.Parameters.Add("Sdate", SqlDbType.Date).Value = txtHStart_Date.Text
    HRequestInsert.Parameters.Add("Edate", SqlDbType.Date).Value = txtHEnd_Date.Text
    HRequestInsert.Parameters.Add("NoofDays", SqlDbType.Decimal).Value = txtNoofDays.Text
    HRequestInsert.Parameters.Add("notes", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = TxtHRequestNotes.Text

    ' execute commands
    HRequestConnection.Open()
    HRequestInsert.ExecuteNonQuery()

    lblHolRequestResponse.Text = "Your holidays request has been saved!
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How have you specified the `decimal` column in the database?  Have you given it precision and scale ([see here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187746.aspx))?  If not, it defaults to `decimal(18,0)` which will give you no figures after the decimal point.

You should give it a type along the lines of `decimal(5,1)` depending on your requirements.

Bear in mind that **precision** is the number of total digits (to the *left and right* of the decimal point) and **scale** is the number to the *right* of the decimal point.  Therefore `decimal(5,1)` could store up to 9999.9.

(I'm assuming you're using SQL Server)

Comment: Thanks..this worked :) However now the values which were just for example 2 are 2.0.. can these not just show as a single number and only the values which need a decimal show or is it a case of all or nothing?

Comment: It will be stored in SQL as 2.0.  You could present it to the user in the TextBox any way you like as long as you write the original value to the database.